# kong HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kong-ingress

We are using kong v2.2 as ingress controller,

some of our requests got an error:
`HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream`

And they are not passed from kong to our backend servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation of the nginx http2 directive:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2_max_field_size
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2_max_header_size

We can see that both directives has a small default value:
The default value for http2_max_field_size is 4k, and for http2_max_header_size is 16k.

We increased them both using the following environment variables(kong configmap):

`KONG_NGINX_HTTP_HTTP2_MAX_FIELD_SIZE: 16k`
`KONG_NGINX_HTTP_HTTP2_MAX_HEADER_SIZE: 64k`